# function that takes in and returns multiple values

Tags: python, arrays, function, if-statement

Say I have a function that calculates and returns an value:

```
h = 4.13566733*10**-15
c = 2.99792458*10**(8+9)


def func(x):
    for i in w:
        A = h*c/i
    return A


w = [1]
print func(w)
```

Fine. But if w is a larger array, say:

```
w = [1 ,2, 3, 4]
```

The func returns for the last value in w (4). Understandebly as that is the last item in the for-loop.
But how can I make the func return an array with all 4 values, something like:

```
[1239, 619, 413, 309]
```

??

Comment: Your function isn't using the argument that's getting passed in.  You should do `for i in x`, not `for i in w`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python supports passing multiple arguments, and returning multiple values. That said, you can change your code to:

```
def func(w):
    return [h*c/i for i in w]
```

If you now call this, you can get the required array:

```
>>> w = [1 ,2, 3, 4]
>>> func(w)
[1239.8418743309974, 619.9209371654987, 413.2806247769991, 309.96046858274934]
```

As for calling with multiple arguments and returning multiple examples, consider the following example method, which takes 2 inputs and returns 3 outputs:

```
>>> def get_product_modulo_dividend(x, y):
...     return x*y, x%y, x/y
>>> get_product_modulo_dividend(100, 10)
(1000, 0, 10)
```

Comment: Nice, that was simple and quick! @mu

Answer (score 1):

Make your `A` a list and append each result to that list

```
h = 4.13566733*10**-15
c = 2.99792458*10**(8+9)


def func(x):
    A = []
    for i in w:
        A.append(h*c/i)
    return A


w = [1,2,3,4]
print func(w)
```

This outputs:

```
[1239.8418743309974, 619.92093716549869, 413.2806247769991, 309.96046858274934]
```

Answer (score 1):

this is similar to what at @mu posted, but it seems like your function is operating on single values that are not connected together and might be more flexible implemented as only taking a number as a param.

```
h = 4.13566733*10**-15
c = 2.99792458*10**(8+9)

def func(x):
  return h*c / x

w = [1,2,3,4]
print([func(x) for x in w])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`, for example.

```
h = 4.13566733*10**-15
c = 2.99792458*10**(8+9)

def func(x):
  return h*c/x

w = [1,2,3]
print map(func, w)
```

Will return [1239.8418743309974, 619.9209371654987, 413.2806247769991]

And you can use more elegant way (as for me):

```
h = 4.13566733*10**-15
c = 2.99792458*10**(8+9)
w = [1,2,3]
result = map(lambda (x): h*c/x, w)
```

Is returns also [1239.8418743309974, 619.9209371654987, 413.2806247769991].

Comment: @gabe sounds strange because it worked for me (py2.7). The result is `[413.2806247769991, 413.2806247769991, 413.2806247769991]`. Here the code: http://repl.it/aaf

Comment: Those are the wrong values (they're all identical). Each time `i` will take a value of `1`, since the input `x` is never used in `func`.

Comment: Hmm.. Didn't noticed. Thank you! I've updated my answer.